# regex lenght of a list of numbers from a file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Hello i want filter some numbers from a file and the only way  i know is with regexp but it seems returned array is empty. Here is how my `failed.txt` looks like

```
015-05-12 18:57:11,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40747984729 failed, trying time 98 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:07:13,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40731109381 failed, trying time 98 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:14:16,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40766368165 failed, trying time 104 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:17:31,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40755129209 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:20:41,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40760015914 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:23:22,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40763297631 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:28:52,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40769564718 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:39:13,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40722494529 failed, trying time 99 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:44:43,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40751013760 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:47:06,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40766223398 failed, trying time 103 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:49:01,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40730263329 failed, trying time 106 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:51:25,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40784114631 failed, trying time 98 sec. Retries: 2.
2015-05-12 19:53:59,4, modem1: Sending SMS (part 1/2) to 40766844650 failed, trying time 98 sec. Retries: 2.
```

and here is my php code that is not working to extract the failed number

```
$regexp = '/^[0-9]{5,11}$/';
preg_match_all($regexp, file_get_contents('http://test.ro/failed.txt'), $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$keys = array_unique($keys);
var_dump($keys);
```

Comment: `/^[...` is "at the start of the string, there must be between 5 and 11 digits". your text does NOT have that. it has 4 digits, a dash, 2 digits, another dash, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace anchors with word boundary `\b`

```
$regexp = '/\b[0-9]{5,11}\b/';
```